# Malicious software runs on the background of Android phone, but I cannot see it - how to find and remove it?

Tags: security, malware

I know that a malicious malware/spyware has been installed on my Samsung Galaxy S3 phone and I constantly get the message to close apps not in use because they drain my battery. But I do not have anything running. I have about 3-4 apps, others were turned off/updates uninstalled a long time ago.

So the questions are not if my phone is infected - I know it is. The question is, how to find and remove it?

Comment: It's not clear how do you know that a malware / spyware has been installed on your phone. I'm afraid no one will be able to help you. Please add necessary details to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [AVG Antivirus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antivirus) or maybe [Malwarebytes' Antimalware](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.malwarebytes.antimalware) which I use a lot and it's really a good app.

Answer (score 0):

The app [List My Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.onyxbits.listmyapps) lists all the apps installed on a device (including malware). Use this to identify the suspicious app and try to uninstall it from system settings.